# How to reset default button focus styling on safari?

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

Is there any way to remove this gray overlay on buttons, links and inputs on safari? I made custom styling for :focus state, but can’t get rid of default behaviour. It causes the annoying flicker.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the webkit-highlight to be transparent: (the Box class will represent your element, change the class name to suit)

```
.box {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Also, try checking the pseduo :before & :after elements of the item